# Replacing non-Latin chars with Latin counterparts like Phonebook App

Tags: iphone, ios, unicode, casting, char

I have a phonebook app where I generate the title for section headers by comparing the first letters of entries.

The indexes are predefined so I expect letters to be assigned from A-Z and for numbers #.

The problem is there are many letter with accents including ü, İ, ç etc in many languages. In my approach, since these chars do not fall under the range A-Z, they are assigned to # which is not desired.

The native iOS Phonebook app assigns for example ü to U and so on. Is there a simple way to make this casting without defining a set of chars?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out Unicode Normalization. You probably want some combination of NFD and extraction of the adequate data. If you look at [this file](http://www.unicode.org/Public/reconstructed/1.0.1/UnicodeData.txt) from Unicode, you will see something like

> 00E9;LATIN SMALL LETTER E ACUTE;Ll;0;L;0065 0301;;;;N;;;00C9;;00C9

Where `00E9`, ie 'é', is decomposed as `0065 0301`. You pick up `0065` (a), and discard `0301` (´). This file should get you started nicely. There may be equivalent functions in Objective-C/iOS, but I wouldn't know where to start...